# Saving entity with id value JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

So, let's say that I have an object A which has a many to many relationship with object B(B is an entity to a config table in the db which means that the values are not insertable nor updateable.

If I want to save an object A with a list of objects B, is it enough if I provide only the ID of the object B or should I do a query with the ID to get the entire object in order for JPA to do the mapping?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA you need the "complete" objects before persisting them. This means that in your case you will need to get all objects `B` from the database, then set them in the object `A` that you are trying to persist and then finally save object `A`.